# msdeploy and runCommand results in vague "Access is denied" error

Tags: msdeploy

I have a preexisting deployment process which successfully deploys a site to its staging environment.  Attempting the same process against a new production environment is failing at the point where we try to invoke msdeploy's "runCommand" option.

We're using pstrami, which ultimately uses msdeploy twice.  msdeploy successfully copies files to the target machine.  pstrami then tries to use msdeploy a second time, this time to use "runCommand" on a bat file that should actually install everything under IIS.

The first use of msdeploy works, copying the files.  Therefore, the credentials we're working with are correct.

The second use of msdeploy outputs the following:

```
Info: Updating runCommand (bootstrap.bat).
Warning: Access is denied.
```

It appears that bootstrap.bat is not actually reached.  It is unclear who is being denied access to what.  I suspect that the user is not allowed to perform "runCommand", but advice about runCommand online is inconsistent and has not revealed anything different between my staging and production machines.

What should it take for msdeploy 'runCommand' to be granted access?

Answer (score 0):

MSDeploy supports configuring permissions on a per-provider basis, so your hosting provider may have disabled it. It might be worth checking with them.